# Spring dependency injection and generic class

Tags: spring, generics, dependency-injection

Sorry for my English. I can not to do dependency injection for generic class in spring. Generic class:

```
abstract class BaseBO<Id, Entity, DAOClass extends DAO<Id, Entity>> implements BO<Id, Entity, DAOClass> {
    DAOClass dao;

    public DAOClass getDAO() {
        return dao;
    }
    //...
}
```

Use generic class:

```
public class TaskBO extends BaseBO<Long, Task, TaskDAO> implements BO<Long, Task, TaskDAO> {

}
```

I want to do dependency injection in a class `TaskBO` for property `TaskDAO`. 
But I can only to set dependency `TaskDAO` via a interface `DAO` for bean `TaskBO`:

```
<bean id="TaskBO" class="com.otv.model.bo.TaskBO">
        <property name="DAO" ref="TaskDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="TaskDAO" class="com.otv.model.dao.TaskDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

How to set dependency injection via class `TaskDAO`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach stacktrace with error if you have one.

Before all use consistent case for property accessor:

```
abstract class BaseBO<Id, Entity, DAOClass extends DAO<Id, Entity>> implements BO<Id, Entity, DAOClass> {
    DAOClass dao;

    public DAOClass getDao() {
        return dao;
    }
    //...
}
```

Most probably you need a setter for BaseBO.dao property

```
public void setDao(DAOClass dao) {
  this.dao = dao;
}
```

or

```
public class TaskBO extends BaseBO<Long, Task, TaskDAO> implements BO<Long, Task, TaskDAO> {

    public void setDao(TaskDAO dao) {
      super.dao = dao;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand correctly, error in the other. In `BaseBO` there is a method `setDAO(DAOClass dao)`. If I add in TaskMB `@ManagedProperty(value="#{TaskBO}") BO<Long, Task, TaskDAO> taskBO;`,  it is working. But if I add `@ManagedProperty(value="#{TaskBO}") TaskBO taskBO;`, it return error `Unable to set property taskBO for managed bean taskMB`.

Comment: If add interface `@ManagedProperty(value="#{TaskBO}") ITaskBO taskBO;`, it is working!